# Add to $PATH with Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04

I want to add `PATH` on `Linux Ubuntu 18.04` from file `path.sh` , my file include :

```
 #!/bin/bash
 export PATH="$PATH:/root/.local/bin"
```

`chmod+x path.sh` , but when i run it `./path.sh` Path not add when i type `echo $PATH` .

but when i type in terminal `export PATH="$PATH:/root/.local/bin"` it added to my `PATH` .

Am I **miss** something on my file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consult `man bash`:

> ```
> export [-fn] [name[=word]] ...
> export -p
>        The  supplied names are marked for automatic export to the envi-
>        ronment of subsequently executed commands.
> ```

Note *"subsequently executed commands"*, therefore the effect of your script ends, once the script ends.

Answer (score 2):

```
source path.sh
```

add this step is fine.